# How can I see the command line that was used by CodeBlocks that caused GCC to compile a program?

Tags: gcc, command-line, codeblocks

How can I see the command line that was used by CodeBlocks that caused GCC to compile a program?  I have looked all over the CodeBlocks IDE but can not find it.  A web search only yields ways to add flags to the command line--I know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Settings" > "Compiler.." > "Other settings" tab and select "Full Command Line" from the drop list. After doing this I was able to see the full command in the "Build log" section on the bottom, right after compiling. I hope it works for you too

Found here: https://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=662.0